# Multiple same keys in the JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Googled for the last couple hours, but couldn't find the way of doing it without writing any function or using `map()`.

I'm trying to find the easiest way of getting `price` value in the following object structure by searching first two keys.

```
var itemPrices = {
    '1': { '1': 1000 },
    '1': { '2': 1000 },
    '1': { '3': 1100 },
    '2': { '1': 900 },
    '2': { '2': 900 },
    '3': { '4': 2200 },
    '3': { '5': 700 },
    '4': { '1': 1200 },
    '4': { '2': 1200 },
};

console.log(itemPrices['1']['1']); // Returns undefined because it's overwritten by `['1']['3']`.
```

I'm using PHP to generate this object:

```
echo "  var itemPrices = {\n";
foreach($_SESSION['item_prices'] as $item_price) {
    $category_id = $item_price['categoryid'];
    $type_id = $item_price['typeid'];
    $price = $item_price['price'];
    echo "      '$category_id': { '$type_id': $price },\n";
}
echo "  };\n";
```

Please help.

Comment: @depperm: understood, any possible way of keeping them the same? I'm even okay using JavaScript array (it wont let me set the keys in non-ordered numbers).

Comment: Use an array, or merge objects. And don't try to encode JSON yourself. Use json_encode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a proper JavaScript Object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

```
var itemPrices = {
    '1': { 
        '1': 1000,
        '2': 1000,
        '3': 1100
    },
    '2': { 
        '1': 900,
        '2': 900 
    },
    '3': {
        '4': 2200,
        '5': 700
    },
    '4': {
        '1': 1200,
        '2': 1200
    },
};
```

Should allow you to do

```
console.log(itemPrices['1']['1']);
```

You'll also need to tweak your PHP script a bit to get it to output properly!

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f8kbca3h/

Comment: Tweaked PHP script, but it's so poor of JavaScript.

Comment: Don't confuse object literals with JSON What you have is an object literal, not JSON.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, I appreciate the clarification. Edited my answer and added a link to the JS Objects page on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to have this structure?:

```
var itemPrices = {
  1: {
    1: 1000,
    2: 2000,
    3: 3000
  },
  2: {
    1: 1000,
    2: 2000
  }
}
```

You can achieve the same:

```
var itemPrices = {};
itemPrices[1] = {};
itemPrices[1][1] = 1000;
itemPrices[1][2] = 2000;
itemPrices[2] = {};
itemPrices[2][1] = 1000;
itemPrices[2][2] = 2000;
```

Comment: can you set [1] without setting [0] first?

Comment: It's a hash object, not an array. Every literal can be key.

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = array();
foreach($_SESSION['item_prices'] as $item_price) {
    $category_id = $item_price['categoryid'];
    $type_id = $item_price['typeid'];
    $price = $item_price['price'];
    if (!isset($data[$category_id]))
    {
        $data[$category_id] = array();
    }
    $data[$category_id][$type_id] = $price;
}
echo "  var itemPrices = ".json_encode($data).";\n";
```

Comment: Too much coding, ended by with:  foreach($_SESSION['item_prices'] as $category_id => $item_price) {

  echo "  '$category_id': {\n";

  foreach($item_price as $item_type_id => $price) {
   echo "   '$item_type_id': $price,\n";
  }

  echo "  },\n";

 }

Comment: Don't encode JSON yourself. Don't encode JSON yourself. Did I mention **don't encode JSON yourself**?

Comment: Why not? Escaping stuff? That's handled by PHP.

Comment: That's handled by php if you use json_encode, not if you print out stuff yourself.

Comment: There is big disadvantage: I can't control how json_encode() does nice output with tabs and \n's .... =)))

Comment: JSON_PRETTY_PRINT is your friend.